# 0KB of repo size on GitHub while testing with git-lfs

Tags: git, github, git-lfs

I have a repository contains a .psd file which is tracked by [git-lfs](https://git-lfs.github.com/).

As the man-page stated that git-lfs will be

> storing the file contents on a remote server like GitHub.com or GitHub
>   Enterprise.

I assumed that my repo size would be smaller than one that contains an actual .psd file.

To test this assumption, I created two repos like:

repo_1 - include a .psd tracked by git-lfs

repo_2 - include a .psd untracked

then pushed both to GitHub.

---

Ways I tried to get repos sizes & the results:

1. checking on GitHub's Settings > Repositories page:

[image]

2. accessing information via [GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/) like:
   https://api.github.com/repos/myUserName/myRepoName

[image]

3. typing `curl https://api.github.com/repos/myUserName/myRepoName | grep size` in terminal:

[image]

---

**TL;DR**

Checking my GitHub repos sizes I get 0KB represented.

In order to check the differences of repos with and without git-lfs,

what else can I do?